# When comparing 2 variables output always the same

Tags: python-3.x, variables, output

this is my code for a quiz with ten question.the problem is that whenever I write the answer (the answer gets printed before asking the question) it always say incorrect. please take into consideration that I am very bad at the language and don't correct what doesn't need to be fixed. Thankyou.

```
from random import randint

name = input("what is your name?")
score = 0
qn = 0

def q():
    global qn
    global name
    global score
    qn += 1

    if qn < 11:

        num1 = randint(1,12)

        s = randint(1,3)

        num2 = randint(1,12)

        if s == 1:
            symbal = '+'
            answer = num1 + num2

        elif s == 2:
            symbal = '-'
            answer = num1 - num2

        elif s == 3:
            symbal = '*'
            answer = num1 * num2

        print(answer)

        print(num1 ,symbal ,num2)

        sanswer = input("= ?")

        if answer == sanswer:
            score += 1
            print("correct!!!")

        else:
            print("incorrect")

        q()
    else:
        global name
        print("""welldone""")
        print(name)
q()
```

Comment: Its working fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

name = input("what is your name?")
score = 0
qn = 0

def q():
    global qn
    global name
    global score
    qn += 1

    if qn < 11:

        num1 = randint(1,12)

        s = randint(1,3)

        num2 = randint(1,12)

        if s == 1:
            symbal = '+'
            answer = num1 + num2

        elif s == 2:
            symbal = '-'
            answer = num1 - num2

        elif s == 3:
            symbal = '*'
            answer = num1 * num2

        print(num1 ,symbal ,num2)

        sanswer = int(input("= ?"))

        print(answer)


        if answer == sanswer:
            score += 1
            print("correct!!!")

        else:
            print("incorrect")

        q()
    else:
        global name
        print("""welldone""")
        print(name)
q()
```

2 mistake you have:

first: you shouldn't put `print(answer)` before input

second: you should `sanswer = int(input("= ?"))` use int() because what you take with input is string

and a simple suggestion try not to use global when coding.